# iperf connect failed: Operation now in progress

Tags: networking

I have installed iperf on two computers using `yum install iperf`.

On server A, i ran `iperf -s`, on server B I ran `iperf -c ipv4here`

I got this error:

```
connect failed: Operation now in progress
```

I looked for this error, but I couldn't find any explanation. 
What does it mean? What can be done to fix it?

I am on Centos 7. I also tried to connect to iperf predefined server with:

```
iperf -c bouygues.iperf.fr
```

And was successful on machine A and B. With that said, there must be an issue on my end.

Comment: I can verify this on current CentOS 7

Answer (score 3):

According to [the manual page for `connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html), the error `EINPROGRESS` ("Operation now in progress") doesn't actually refer to an error condition. Rather, it means that "The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be completed immediately." Any program that uses nonblocking sockets should recognize this and handle it internally (by select()ing for completion or something). As iperf is instead failing and presenting that error to you, it would appear that you have somehow found a bug in it, which you should report to the developers.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the server is running the same version of iperf.

I had the same message when I ran `iperf3` on server and tried `iperf` command on client.

What helped was to install `iperf3` on the client and run it.

Answer (score 2):

Also check the firewall. I was getting this error.

I found that `sudo ufw disable` allowed `iperf` to work. And then `sudo ufw enable` of course afterwards to put the firewall back up.